# Need some advice on best way to write Large reporting query from a fairly complex source

Tags: performance, view, multiple-databases, cross-join

After searching through other answers to see if this particular question has already been asked (and other flavours have been asked - just not covering off everything I need to enquire about), I would like to pose the following scenario and ask for advise on the most efficient way to create this reporting query. This is a verbose post and I am not allowed to post any of the T-SQL code unfortunately - my employer has expressly forbid that.

One thing I have learned over the years is that there are loads more people out there that know a heck of a lot more than me - so after searching and not finding what you need, just ask someone :)

All tables have primary keys and if there are tables that link to child tables, there are foreign keys in place. The database and report server is SQL 2008 R2. The server runs 128GB RAM and is an 4CPU Quad core hyper threaded beastie.

First, I have a set of tables that contain Locations, Sections and Areas. A Location is linked through a mapping table to a Section - there are multiple locations to a section, sections are linked to Areas through a mapping table and there are multiple sections to an Area. These table are all located in Database "A". I have created a view in a separate Database "B" that represents the Area - Section - Location linkages in a nice result set that executes quickly. I call this the LocationSectionArea View.

In database "B", thousands of users are entering their daily statistics regarding all sorts of categories of their work. There are at present 91 categories. Each category will contain subcategories which vary from about 3 to as many as 25. The number of categories and subcategories can change at any time with more being added or removed through an administration interface. I have created a View that represents these links and returns a result set called the CategorySubCategoryFields view.

The information being collected for each of these categories/Sub category links varies - some require about 8 different fields, while some require 3, and some only 1. These fields are linked to their appropriate sub categories. This is again contained in database "B".

I have constructed a view that nicely pulls this data together in this database which ends up with a large matrix of results that presents the data in a way that can be reported on quite easily, and the views execution so far seems to be quite acceptable in speed. I call this the UserStatsView. This is contained in database "B".

Now - the users entering the data are assigned to one of the locations mentioned earlier. The results are required to show all Locations within a Section, and all sections within an area, as well as for each location show each of the categories and sub categories for that category. This then needs to be linked to the results from the UserStatsView so you end up with a rather large matrix of these results intermingled with a lot of 0's where there are no results - but they are created for reporting purposes.

The reports have to be allow a user to , for example, select a Section, and then produce a report of all Locations contained within that section, along with a tally of the results entered by users for that location - for each Category-SubCategory combination there is. It must present all locations for the section and all Categories-SubCategories regardless of if there are actual results entered by users or not. So there may be a lot of 0's on some of the reports.

To achieve this I created a results view that cross joins the LocationSectionArea  with the CategorySubCategoryFields view. This created the basic matrix that I want. I then left join this matrix to the results of the UserStatsView, joining on the LocationId, CategoryId and SubCategoryId to insert the results for the users for the locations. This is all created in database "B".

Now this all works and is "ok" provided you supply enough filters in the final where clause to reduce the number of records. As you can imaging - if they try to run a report with a larger results set - it starts to get very slow. (ie, date range covering 6 months for all locations takes longer than 30 seconds)

Part of my problem is I believe that the Location information is linked in from database "A" and the view constructed is contained in database "B" along with all the views tables and records for all other information required for this report.

Another part is I believe the very large and complex cross join created that is then linked to the view of users results. The cross join is a Cartesian result with no indexes or related data until it is joined with the UserStatsView result set.

And the third problem I believe is the fact that data is being "created" to fill in all the blanks in order to produce the results structure that can then be fed into SSRS. I have seen that table spooling and hash joins take up a lot of the execution time, as well as lookups from the database with the locations, sections and Areas. These were all shown through the query execution estimated plan.

What I am asking is if anyone knows if there is a better way of generating this result set given the criteria outlined above. Have I completely missed a really simple and faster way of doing this, which is highly probable :). If someone can suggest what I should research I will happily go off and do it - just not sure what to research at this stage?

Cheers

Rod.

Update: the following is the table structure that defines the two databases,. Obviously there is more in the real tables, but this is the crux of how they hang together. Please excuse such a large post - I have removed everything except the key fields and some data fields so you can see how the tables are structured. The table names and field names have been changed to generic names with a lot of extra fields removed so I can post the code.

---

Database A

```
**Location Table**
LocationId BIGINT PK
LocationName Varchar(100)


**Section Table**
SectionId Bigint PK
SectionName varchar(100)



**Area Table**
AreaId Bigint PK
AreaName varchar(100)



**LocationSectionMap Table**
LocSecId Bigint PK
LocationId Bigint FK Index to Location Table
SectionId BigInt FK Index to Section Table




**SectionAreaMap Table**
SecAreaId Bigint PK 
SectionId Bigint FK Index to Section Table
AreaId Bigint FK Index to Area Table
```

---

Database B

```
**Categories Table** 
CategoryId Bigint PK
categoryName varchar(100)



**SubCategories Table**
SubCategoryId Bigint
CategoryId Bigint FK to Categories Table 
SubCategoryType Int
FieldTypeId Int (1, 2, 3 or 4)


**UserStats Table**
UserStatId bigint PK
UserId Bigint
StartDate DateTime
EndDate DateTime
LocationId Bigint --> this is the location ID in Location table in database A
SectionId Bigint --> this is the Section ID in Section Table in database A
AreaId Bigint --> this is the Area ID of the Area Table in database A



**FieldType1 Table**
FieldType1Id bigint PK
UserStatId  Bigint FK to UserStats Table
SubCategoryId Bigint FK to Subcategories Table
Value1 int
Value2 int





**FieldType2 Table**
FieldType2Id bigint PK
UserStatId  Bigint FK to UserStats Table
SubCategoryId Bigint FK to Subcategories Table
Value1 int 
Value2 int 
Value4 int
Value5 int
Value6 int
Value7 int
Value8 int
Value9 int
Value10 int


**FieldType3 Table**
FieldType3Id bigint PK
UserStatId  Bigint FK to UserStats Table
SubCategoryId Bigint FK to Subcategories Table
Value1 int
Value2 int
Value11 int
Value12 int
Value13 int
Value14 int
Value15 int
Value16 int


**FieldType4 Table**
FieldType4Id bigint PK
UserStatId  Bigint FK to UserStats Table
SubCategoryId Bigint FK to Subcategories Table
CombinedValue1And2 int



**SubCategoryAssociations Table**
SubCategoryAssociationId Int PK
ReportOfSubCategoryId bigint FK to Subcategories Table
IncludeValuesFromSubcategoryId Bigint FK to Subcategories Table
```

Views:
Area-Section-Location View in Database A  (vwAreasSectionsAndLocations)

```
SELECT     A.AreaId, A.AreaName, C.SectionId, C.SectionName, E.LocationId, E.LocationName
FROM         DatabaseA.dbo.tblAreas AS A INNER JOIN
                      DatabaseA.dbo.tblAreaSections AS B ON A.AreaId = B.AreaId INNER JOIN
                      DatabaseA.dbo.tblSections AS C ON B.SectionId = C.SectionId INNER JOIN
                      DatabaseA.dbo.tblSectionLocations AS D ON C.SectionId = D.SectionId INNER JOIN
                      DatabaseA.dbo.tblLocations AS E ON D.LocationId = E.LocationId
```

Category-SubCategory View in Database B   (vwCategoryAndSubCategory)

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.tblCategories.CategoryId, 
          dbo.tblCategories.CategoryName, 
                      dbo.tblSubCategory.SubCategoryId, 
                      dbo.tblSubCategory.SubCategoryname, 
              dbo.tblSubCategory.SubCategoryTypeId
FROM         dbo.tblCategories INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tblSubCategory ON dbo.tblCategories.CategoryId = dbo.tblSubCategory.CategoryId
ORDER BY dbo.tblCategories.CategoryName, dbo.tblSubCategory.SubCategoryname
```

View that Cross Joins the two views to create the required results matrix (without Results)  (vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory)

```
SELECT     dbo.vwCategoryAndSubCategory.CategoryId, dbo.vwCategoryAndSubCategory.CategoryName, 
                      dbo.vwCategoryAndSubCategory.CategoryPlacementOrder, dbo.vwCategoryAndSubCategory.IsStandardDaybookEntryCategory, 
                      dbo.vwCategoryAndSubCategory.SubCategoryId, dbo.vwCategoryAndSubCategory.SubCategoryname, dbo.vwCategoryAndSubCategory.SubCategoryTypeId, 
                      dbo.vwCategoryAndSubCategory.SubCategoryPlacementOrder, dbo.vwAreasSectionsAndLocations.AreaId, dbo.vwAreasSectionsAndLocations.AreaName, 
                      dbo.vwAreasSectionsAndLocations.SectionId, dbo.vwAreasSectionsAndLocations.SectionName, dbo.vwAreasSectionsAndLocations.LocationId, 
                      dbo.vwAreasSectionsAndLocations.LocationName
FROM         dbo.vwCategoryAndSubCategory CROSS JOIN
                      dbo.vwAreasSectionsAndLocations
```

View that Creates the Use Stats Results  (vwUserStatsResults)

```
SELECT      dbo.tblUserStats.UserStatId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.UserId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.LocationId, 
        dbo.tblUserStats.SectionId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.AreaId,                       
            dbo.tblUserStats.StartDate, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.EndDate, 
    dbo.tblFieldType1.CategoryId, 
    dbo.tblFieldType1.SubCategoryId, 
            1 AS FieldTypeId, 
    (dbo.tblFieldType1.Value1 + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(A.Value1)
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType1 A
                          WHERE     A.SubCategoryId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId) AND dbo.tblFieldType1.UserStatId = A.UserStatId), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(A.Value1)
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType2 A
                          WHERE     A.SubCategoryId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId) AND dbo.tblFieldType1.UserStatId = A.UserStatId), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(A.Value1)
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType3 A
                          WHERE     A.SubCategoryId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId) AND dbo.tblFieldType1.UserStatId = A.UserStatId), 0)) 
                  AS Value1, (dbo.tblFieldType1.Value2 + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(A.Value2)
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType1 A
                          WHERE     A.SubCategoryId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId) AND dbo.tblFieldType1.UserStatId = A.UserStatId), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(A.Value2)
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType2 A
                          WHERE     A.SubCategoryId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId) AND dbo.tblFieldType1.UserStatId = A.UserStatId), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(A.Value2)
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType3 A
                          WHERE     A.SubCategoryId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId) AND dbo.tblFieldType1.UserStatId = A.UserStatId), 0)) 
                  AS Value2, Value1 + Value2 AS CombinedValue1And2, 0 AS Value3, 0 AS Value4, 
                  0 AS Value5, 0 AS Value6, 0 AS Value7, 0 AS Value8, 
                  0 AS Value9, 0 AS Value10, 0 AS Value11, 0 AS Value12, 0 AS Value13, 
                  0 AS Value14, 0 AS Value15, 0 AS Value16
FROM         dbo.tblUserStats INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tblFieldType1 ON dbo.tblUserStats.UserStatId = dbo.tblFieldType1.UserStatId 

UNION ALL

SELECT      dbo.tblUserStats.UserStatId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.UserId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.LocationId, 
            dbo.tblUserStats.SectionId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.AreaId, 
            dbo.tblUserStats.StartDate, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.EndDate, 
    dbo.tblFieldType2.CategoryId, 
    dbo.tblFieldType2.SubCategoryId, 
            2 AS FieldTypeId, 
    dbo.tblFieldType2.Value1 + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(Value1) AS Expr1
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType1 AS A
                          WHERE     (FieldId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      (ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId))) AND (dbo.tblFieldType2.UserStatId = UserStatId)), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(Value1) AS Expr1
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType2 AS A
                          WHERE     (FieldId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      (ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId))) AND (dbo.tblFieldType2.UserStatId = UserStatId)), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(Value1) AS Expr1
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType3 AS A
                          WHERE     (FieldId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      (ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId))) AND (dbo.tblFieldType2.UserStatId = UserStatId)), 0) 
                  AS Value1, dbo.tblFieldType2.Value2 + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(Value2) AS Expr1
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType1 AS A
                          WHERE     (FieldId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      (ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId))) AND (dbo.tblFieldType2.UserStatId = UserStatId)), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(Value2) AS Expr1
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType2 AS A
                          WHERE     (FieldId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      (ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId))) AND (dbo.tblFieldType2.UserStatId = UserStatId)), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(Value2) AS Expr1
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType3 AS A
                          WHERE     (FieldId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      (ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId))) AND (dbo.tblFieldType2.UserStatId = UserStatId)), 0) 
                  AS Value2, dbo.tblFieldType2.Value1 + dbo.tblFieldType2.Value2 AS CombinedValue1And2, 
                  ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType2.Value3, 0), ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType2.Value4, 0), 
                  ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType2.Value5, 0), ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType2.Value6, 0), 
                  ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType2.Value7, 0), ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType2.Value8, 0), 
                  ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType2.Value9, 0), ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType2.Value10, 0), 
                  0 AS Value11, 0 AS Value12, 0 AS Value13, 0 AS Value14, 0 AS Value15, 
                  0 AS Value16
FROM         dbo.tblUserStats INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tblFieldType2 ON dbo.tblUserStats.UserStatId = dbo.tblFieldType2.UserStatId 
UNION ALL
SELECT      dbo.tblUserStats.UserStatId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.UserId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.LocationId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.SectionId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.AreaId, 
            dbo.tblUserStats.StartDate, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.EndDate, 
    dbo.tblFieldType3.CategoryId, 
    dbo.tblFieldType3.SubCategoryId, 
            3 AS FieldTypeId, 
    dbo.tblFieldType3.Value1 + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(Value1) AS Expr1
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType1 AS A
                          WHERE     (FieldId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      (ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId))) AND (dbo.tblFieldType3.UserStatId = UserStatId)), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(Value1) AS Expr1
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType2 AS A
                          WHERE     (FieldId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      (ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId))) AND (dbo.tblFieldType3.UserStatId = UserStatId)), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(Value1) AS Expr1
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType3 AS A
                          WHERE     (FieldId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      (ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId))) AND (dbo.tblFieldType3.UserStatId = UserStatId)), 0) 
                  AS Value1, dbo.tblFieldType3.Value2 + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(Value2) AS Expr1
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType1 AS A
                          WHERE     (FieldId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      (ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId))) AND (dbo.tblFieldType3.UserStatId = UserStatId)), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(Value2) AS Expr1
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType2 AS A
                          WHERE     (FieldId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      (ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId))) AND (dbo.tblFieldType3.UserStatId = UserStatId)), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(Value2) AS Expr1
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType3 AS A
                          WHERE     (FieldId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      (ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId))) AND (dbo.tblFieldType3.UserStatId = UserStatId)), 0) 
                  AS Value2, dbo.tblFieldType3.Value1 + dbo.tblFieldType3.Value2 AS CombinedValue1And2, 0 AS Value3, 
                  0 AS Value4, 0 AS Value5, 0 AS Value6, 0 AS Value7, 
                  0 AS Value8, 0 AS Value9, 0 AS Value10, 
                  ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType3.Value11, 0), ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType3.Value12, 0), 
                  ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType3.Value13, 0), ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType3.Value14, 0), 
                  ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType3.Value15, 0), ISNULL(dbo.tblFieldType3.Value16, 0)
FROM         dbo.tblUserStats INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tblFieldType3 ON dbo.tblUserStats.UserStatId = dbo.tblFieldType3.UserStatId 
UNION ALL
SELECT     dbo.tblUserStats.UserStatId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.UserId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.LocationId, 
            dbo.tblUserStats.SectionId, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.AreaId, 
            dbo.tblUserStats.StartDate, 
    dbo.tblUserStats.EndDate, 
    dbo.tblFieldType4.CategoryId, 
    dbo.tblFieldType4.SubCategoryId, 
            4 AS FieldTypeId, 
    0 AS Value1, 0 AS Value2, dbo.tblFieldType4.CombinedValue1And2 + (ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(A.Value1)
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType1 A
                          WHERE     A.SubCategoryId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId) AND dbo.tblFieldType4.UserStatId = A.UserStatId), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(A.Value1)
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType2 A
                          WHERE     A.SubCategoryId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId) AND dbo.tblFieldType4.UserStatId = A.UserStatId), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(A.Value1)
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType3 A
                          WHERE     A.SubCategoryId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId) AND dbo.tblFieldType4.UserStatId = A.UserStatId), 0)) 
                  + (ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(A.Value2)
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType1 A
                          WHERE     A.SubCategoryId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId) AND dbo.tblFieldType4.UserStatId = A.UserStatId), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(A.Value2)
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType2 A
                          WHERE     A.SubCategoryId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId) AND dbo.tblFieldType4.UserStatId = A.UserStatId), 0) 
                  + ISNULL
                      ((SELECT     SUM(A.Value2)
                          FROM         dbo.tblFieldType3 A
                          WHERE     A.SubCategoryId IN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT IncludeValuesFromSubCategoryId
                                                      FROM          dbo.tblSubCategoryAssociations
                                                      WHERE      ReportOnSubCategoryId = A.SubCategoryId) AND dbo.tblFieldType4.UserStatId = A.UserStatId), 0)) 
                  AS CombinedValue1And2, 0 AS Value3, 0 AS Value4, 0 AS Value5, 0 AS Value6, 
                  0 AS Value7, 0 AS Value8, 0 AS Value9, 0 AS Value10, 
                  0 AS Value11, 0 AS Value12, 0 AS Value13, 0 AS Value14, 0 AS Value15, 
                  0 AS Value16
FROM         dbo.tblUserStats INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tblFieldType4 ON dbo.tblUserStats.UserStatId = dbo.tblFieldType4.UserStatId
```

And finally the view that pulls it all together   (vwReportResults)

Posted in another entry due to character limitations

Comment: You don't need to post the actual table/field names... But I'd be hard pressed to wager that you'll get a good answer from the wall-of-text.

Comment: I'll piece together the structure so you get an idea of how it hangs together.

Comment: I am "cleansing" the views and sql code as best I can to make it generic - taking a while - post back soon.

Answer (score 0):

Continued from Previous Post due to character restrictions...

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.categoryId, 
        dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.categoryName, 
                  dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.SubCategoryId, 
                  dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.SubCategoryName, 
        dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.FieldTypeId, 
                  dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.AreaId, 
                  dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.AreaName, 
        dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.SectionId, 
                  dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.SectionName, 
        dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.LocationId, 
                  dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.LocationName, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.UserStatsId, 0) AS UserStatsId, 
                  ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.UserId, 0) AS UserId, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.LocationId, 0) AS LocationId, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.SectionId, 0) AS SectionId, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.AreaId, 0) AS AreaId, 
                    ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.StartDate, N'2000-01-01') AS StartDate, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.EndDate, N'2000-01-01') AS EndDate, 
                    ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value1, 0) AS Value1, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value2, 0) AS Value2, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.CombinedValue1And2, 0) AS CombinedValue1And2, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value3, 0) AS Value3, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value4, 0) AS Value4, 
                    ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value5, 0) AS Value5, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value6, 0) AS Value6, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value7, 0) AS Value7, 
                    ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value8, 0) AS Value8, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value9, 0) AS Value9, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value10, 0) AS Value10, 
                    ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value11, 0) AS Value11, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value12, 0) AS Value12, 
                    ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value13, 0) AS Value13,   
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value14, 0) AS Value14, 
        ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value15, 0) AS Value15, 
                    ISNULL(dbo.vwUserStatsResults.Value16, 0) AS Value16
FROM         dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.vwUserStatsResults ON dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.LocationId = dbo.vwUserStatsResults.LocationId AND 
                  dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.SubCategoryId = dbo.vwUserStatsResults.SubCategoryId AND 
                  dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.FieldTypeId = dbo.vwUserStatsResults.FieldTypeId AND 
                  dbo.vwAreaSectionLocationCategorySubCategory.categoryId = dbo.vwUserStatsResults.categoryId
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have discovered my own answer after finding and reading an article about cross join performance and the do's and don'ts, along with an article on changing your views to Table-Valued User-Defined Functions, I am simply going to convert the views to TV-UDFs and filter the "Views" from the onset to reduce the workload the SQL Server needs to do to. This should hopefully reduce the volumes of data being returned and stop or reduce the table spooling.